# Measuring (Un)likelihood of Random Preferences

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

Suppose we have a set of users who are interacting with posts on a social media feed. Any post $p_i$ can be clicked on, and we collect clicks for each user. Also, each post $p_i$ has a summary statistic of click-thru-rate $r_i$ defined as:

$$r_i:=\frac{\mbox{# clicked on }p_i}{\mbox{# impressions of }p_i}.$$

Let $u_i$ be a set of "real" users, and $v_j$ be a set of "bot" users. Real users $u_i$, on average, click on a post $p_j$ at roughly rate $r_j$. Whereas bot users flip a biased coin for each post, clicking on it if it comes up as heads. Most likely the bias is fixed across clicks, but perhaps some bots vary the bias. For any given user, define their history binary indicators on whether or not they clicked a post. E.g. $H(u_1)=[(p_1,1),(p_{24},0),...]$ means that user $u_1$ clicked post $p_1$ but not post $p_{24}$ (the history includes only posts that were impressed on $u_1$).

**Main Question:**
Using **only** summary statistics such as $r_i$ and the history of each user, what is the *optimum measure* whose score separates real users from bots? For simplicity we can assume the bot coin flips have individual but fixed biases.

As an example, we can use negative loglikelihood:

$$L(H(u_i))=-\frac{1}{|H(u_i)|}\sum_{(p_i,c_i)\in H(u_i)} 1_{c_i=1}\log(r_i)+1_{c_i=0}\log(1-r_i).$$

High scores of the above metric would correspond to unlikely sequences of clicks, thereby correlating with bot users.

My question is, is the above measure optimal in some sense? I could instead try using Wasserstein (Earthmover) distance, by binning user clicks by buckets of click-thru rate, and then measure the deviation from an average good user instead.

On the one hand, I'm guessing most of these measures are equivalent, in the sense that any two measures $M,N$ would satisfy $c_1N< M < c_2 N$. On the other hand, there's obviously information lost in terms of specific user preferences (e.g. correlations between pairs of pages and a given users preferences), so I'm wondering if something like the earthmover distance would theoretically work better here?

Overall, I'm just interested in what the best measure is given as little actual features about the pages and users as possible.

Comment: In your first paragraph, you write "Any **post** $p_i$..." and "...each **page** $p_i$...". Is a post the same as a page?

Comment: @mhdadk: corrected. Thanks

Comment: It is not entirely clear how you propose that the bots act differently to the humans.  Are you saying that bots have a fixed probability of clicking on a post whereas humans vary?  If not that, then what do you say is the difference?

Comment: @Ben: Right, I mean that bots have random preferences. For simplicity yes, we can assume that a given bot $b_i$ clicks each post with probability $q_i$. For simplicity I’ve assumed that the probability of clicks is fixed across posts but ideally I’d like to also consider the case where it varies.

Comment: @Ben: also humans click posts based on their personal interests and preferences. You can assume that those preferences can roughly be approximated via collaborative filtering.

Comment: @Ben However for the purposes of this question, I think it’s sufficient to just assume that human preferences are not purely random, and on average are captured by the summary statistics $r_i$.

Comment: so you want to differentiate between bots that click on each post with the same probability (maybe different between bots) and humans that click on each post with a post-specific probability r_i?

Comment: @rep_ho: because humans have correlated preferences, there will be individual post clicking probabilities. However I am assuming we have access to the average click rate on posts (which can be assumed to be calculated on human preferences)

Comment: i get it, i am just want to be sure if I understood your question

Comment: It would be interesting if you had a topic/identification associated with each post $p_i$ like “cosmetics”, “exercise”, etc.- then I’d assume a bot would have a uniform distribution of clicks per topic whereas most users are most likely concentrated in 1-2 types of topics